# Import Simpy in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, simpy

I am unable to import simpy in Python 3. It gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-076c1059698e> in <module>
----> 1 import simpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpy'
```

Please tell me a way to do so?

Comment: Why did you expect that it does not give you this error?

Comment: Are you sure that this package was installed before?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the package is installed and available in your environment, as that is a common error when the package is not present.

Run:

```
pip install simpy
```

or if you have separate Python versions on your system:

```
pip3 install simpy
```

Or, if installing from the source code:

```
python setup.py install
```

or,

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook environment. When I run pip install simpy, it gives me this message: Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\Give' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you restart the running Jupyter instance after installation?